# PHP-FPM error log says "Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x47 0x49"

Tags: php

In my PHP-FPM log file I have lot's of rows like the following

```
[18-Sep-2016 03:59:06] WARNING: [pool www] child 5425 said into stderr: "Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x47 0x49"
```

What does it means?

Answer (score 4):

It is a [common error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11310220/why-am-i-getting-the-error-not-a-jpeg-file-starts-with-0x89-0x50). It looks like you are opening a file with `imagecreatefromjpeg`, but it is not a jpeg, it is a gif file, take a look at [this note](https://blog.netspi.com/magic-bytes-identifying-common-file-formats-at-a-glance/) concerning starting bytes.

Comment: That list really thinks [Ogg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogg) and [Matroška](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroska) are archives instead of multimedia containers. It will also only recognize [RAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAR_(file_format)) 5+ archives, not the older ones.

Answer (score 3):

It's most supposely a GIF, as they start with `0x47 0x49`. JPG starts with `0xFF 0xD8 0xFF`. Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures and reconsider your code: do you want to fail it on such cases (filenames alone are never a guarantee for their content), or do you want to react on it by then guessing its format and trying to parse it as such.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are trying to open a jpeg file which is not actually a jpeg or jpg. the file must be of some other format ( png, tiff, bmp or some other) and have been forced renamed as .jpg or .jpeg.